# Inverting a function in a certain region

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

`InverseFunction` works well for globally invertible functions, like

```
f = 2*# + 2 &;
InverseFunction[f]
```

> ```
> 1/2 (-2 + #1) &
> ```

However, how would one for example find the inverse of $f(x)=x^2$ around $(x,f(x))=(1,1)$? My *Mathematica (8.0.4)* gives me a warning about multivalued inverses in this case, as well as the result $-\sqrt{x}$, which is not the branch that I'm looking for:

```
f = #^2 &
InverseFunction[f]
```

> ```
> #1^2 &
>
> InverseFunction::ifun: 
>   Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses. >>
>
> -Sqrt[#1] &
> ```

So: How can I specify the neighbourhood a function should be inverted on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this is helpful :

```
InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[#1^2, 2 > #1 > 0] &]
```

yields

```
ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[#1], 0 <= #1 <= 4] &
```

Then you can use it as an ordinary function, e.g. :

```
Integrate[%[x], {x, 1/2, 3/2}]
```

> ```
> 1/6 (-Sqrt[2] + 3 Sqrt[6])
> ```

or

```
D[ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[#1], 1/4 <= #1 <= 9/4] &[x], x]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[1/(2 Sqrt[x]), 1/4 <= x <= 9/4]
> ```

```
Plot[ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[#1], 1/4 <= #1 <= 9/4] &[x],
                         {x, 1/4, 9/4}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `Solve` (or `Reduce`) to obtain the inverse function and pick the branch that matches your neighbourhood point. A simple approach to obtain $x(y)$ given $y(x)$ and $\{x_0, y (x_0)\}$ is the following:

```
inverseFunc[func_, x_, y_, {a_, b_}] := Module[{f, sols},
    Pick[#, # /. {Rule -> Equal, x -> a, f -> b} // Flatten] &@
      Solve[f == func, {x}] /. f -> y
]
```

For your example of $f(x)=x^2$:

```
inverseFunc[x^2, x, y, {1, 1}]
Out[1]= {{x -> Sqrt[y]}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Being a nonexpert, this is how I invert any kind of weird functions:

```
f[x_]:=x^2;
invf=Interpolation[Table[{f[x],x},{x,3,6,0.1}]]
```

InterpolatingFunction[{{9.,36.}},<>]

```
invf[25]
```

5.

Comment: For numerical inverses, another, possibly better, method is given in the Applications section of the [documentation for `FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html#125456646).