# Problem with InverseFunction of Sqrt

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation

I want to build a table of  `InverseFunction`s, f.e.:

```
Table[InverseFunction[Head[foo][#] &][x], {foo, {Sin[x], Log[x], Sqrt[x]}}]
```

> {ArcSin[x], E^x, Power(-1)[x]}

I' m frustrated by the fact that `Sqrt[x]` evaluates to `Power ...` instead of  `x^2`.
As a temporary fix I have written:

```
Table[InverseFunction[(Head[foo] /. Power -> Sqrt)[#] &][x], {foo, {Sin[x], Log[x], Sqrt[x]}}]
```

which gives the desired result:

> {ArcSin[x], E^x, x^2}

I would like to find a more general and reliable way to prevent this kind of "Head-Substitution". I tried many things with `HoldForm` etc., but to no avail.

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: This is cosely related: [Inverting a function in a certain region](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/inverting-a-function-in-a-certain-region)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `ToString`, make sure you specify `InputForm` (compare `ToString[1/x]` v.s. `ToString[1/x, InputForm]`).

Why not something like this?

```
pureify[f_, x_] := Function @@ {f /. x -> #}

Table[InverseFunction[pureify[foo, x]][x], {foo, {Sin[x], Log[x], Sqrt[x]}}]

(* {ArcSin[x], E^x, x^2} *)
```

Comment: Magnificent and exactly what I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 1):

Without "Head-Substitution", you may achieve it:

```
inv = InverseFunction /@ {Sin, Log, Sqrt}
x // inv // Through
```

out:

```
{ArcSin[x], E^x, x^2}
```

### Edit1:

Yes, to get rid of the arguments I just wanted to suggest you

```
inv = InverseFunction /@ 
  ToExpression /@ (StringTake[#, {1, -4}] & /@ToString /@ {Sin[x], Log[x], Sqrt[x]})
x // inv // Through
```

But I was not so happy with StringTake, you got the more general way finally

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hieron suggestion to start with the "pure" heads I found this solution:

```
GetHeads[fun_] := ToExpression@First@StringSplit[ToString[fun], "["]

f = GetHeads /@ {Sin[x], Log[x], Sqrt[x]}
```

> {Sin, Log, Sqrt}

```
Table[InverseFunction[foo[#] &][x], {foo, f}]
```

> {ArcSin[x], E^x, x^2}