# Inverse of LogIntegral

Tags: special-functions, inverse

I wanted the inverse logarithmic intgral, so I typed

```
InverseFunction[LogIntegral]
```

and received the expected symbolic answer. But when I try to integrate it or even evaluate it it fails. Is there some way to sweet-talk Mathematica into computing this function?

Edit: I was asked for how it fails, here's an example.

```
NIntegrate[n/(InverseFunction[LogIntegral][n])^2, {n, 10^7, 10^9}]
```

yields

> NIntegrate::inumr : The integrand (...)  has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{10000000,1000000000}}.

Comment: You haven't explained how evaluation "fails". It just works nicely, e.g. `InverseFunction[LogIntegral][4]` yields `Root[{-4 + LogIntegral[#1] &, 5.60927669305089035535879233715}]`. When integrating one should expect that in general there is no closed form exprssion, however e.g.`NIntegrate[InverseFunction[LogIntegra l][x], {x, 2, 10}]` yields quite resonably `82.0804`. Perhaps you should remember [Inverting a function in a certain region](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/inverting-a-function-in-a-certain-region/2328#2328)

Comment: @Artes: With an `NIntegrate::inumr` error. I've edited in code.

Comment: `In[138]:= 
f[x_?NumberQ] := y /. FindRoot[LogIntegral[y] == x, {y, 2}];
NIntegrate[n/(f[n])^2, {n, 10^7, 10^9}]

Out[139]= 1.249875*10^17`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: That's not a sensible answer, though. The li^{-1}(x) > x (in fact ~ x log x), so the integral should be less than the integral of 1/x over the same region, which is about 4.6.

Comment: (The true answer should be about 0.01125, or 19 orders of magnitude smaller.)

Comment: Good point. This is better/safer: `f[x_?NumberQ] := y /. FindRoot[LogIntegral[y] == x, {y, x/Log[x]}]`. Now I get `0.0112504860071`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks. (Maybe that should be an answer.) Mathematica is still giving me answers I don't believe (say, integrating up to 10^200 giving an answer of 2*10^7 instead of < 0.1) but at this point it seems hopeless. At least it works for small numbers.

Comment: FWIW the inverse function breaks for integers greater than 3824273 and for reals greater than about 261001.  Just some implementation limits I suppose.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used `x*Log[x]` as initial value. For integrating try `NIntegrate[n/(f[n])^2, {n, 10^7, 10^200}, MinRecursion -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 20]`. One can also mess around with `WorkingPrecision` and the precision and accuracy goals on `FindRoot` and `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems usable at least for moderately large `x`. one could use cutoffs and different start values if this is not useful in smaller ranges.

```
f[x_?NumberQ] := 
 y /. FindRoot[LogIntegral[y] == x, {y, x*Log[x]}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 12]

Two examples:

f[10^200]

(* Out[55]= 4.6565831394119416907*10^202 *)

NIntegrate[n/(f[n])^2, {n, 10^7, 10^200}, MinRecursion -> 5, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]

During evaluation of In[60]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

(* Out[60]= 0.0519673879642 *)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I tweaked the `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal` upward and all was good.

Comment: I edited to fix that `PrecisionGoal` (realized I was specifying it all wrong. It happens.)

Comment: As a minor point, x_?NumericQ would be better than x_?NumberQ so that the function will accept numeric constants such as Pi or E.

Comment: @Charles FWIW, for the particular integral in your question,  substituting `n = LogIntegral[y]` yields this easier to evaluate expression: `NIntegrate[LogIntegral[y]/(Log[y] y^2), {y, f[10^7], f[10^9]}]`, where `f` is the numeric inverse of `LogIntegral` in Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of an aside, but a little variable substitution helps that integral quite a lot.

```
  f[x_?NumberQ] := 
    y /. FindRoot[LogIntegral[y] == x, {y, x*Log[x]}, 
         WorkingPrecision -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 12]
  Log[10] NIntegrate[(10^n/f[10^n])^2 , {n, 7, 200}, 
       MinRecursion -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

> 0.0519674

(~10x faster w/ no warnings about convergence )