# How to plot y(x) v.s x when y(x) is the upper limit of integration?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have a funciton in the following form. But I don't know how to plot it.

$$x=\int_1^{y(x)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{2(t-t\ln t)}}.$$

For example, I want to plot it when $0<x<3$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{NIntegrate[1/Surd[2 t (1 - Log[t]), 2], {t, 1, y}], 
  y}, {y, 1, E}]`

Comment: @ LouisB, thanks, while how can we plot if we only know the range of $x$ rather than that of $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must ask ourselves when does the integral exist?  We see that when $\ln{t}>1$, we have the square root of negative number, which does not really make sense when we are talking about real variables.  So, we say the integral maps y onto x when $0<y<e$.  Outside of this range either the natural log or the square root fails to exist, so there is nothing to plot.

If we tell Mathematica about the range of $y$, we can get a symbolic expression.

```
h = Integrate[1/Surd[2 t (1 - Log[t]), 2], {t, 1, y}, 
   Assumptions -> 1 < y < E];
xmax = h /. y -> E
soln = Solve[x == h, y] // First;
Plot[y /. soln, {x, 0, xmax}]
```

The temptation is to go ahead and plot the "function" `y/.soln` on the interval $1<x<3$, but that would be wrong.  We note that `Solve` gives us a warning that inverse functions are being used.  What has happened is the inverse function introduced an extraneous root.  When we evaluate `NSolve[3 == h, y]` we find that there is no upper limit $y$ for which our expression `h` is 3.

Comment: There is `InverseFunction`, which can be used here. `Plot[InverseFunction[
   Sqrt[2 E Pi] (Erf[1/Sqrt[2]] - Erf[Sqrt[1/2 - 1/2 Log[#1]]]) &][
  x], {x, 0, E}]`. See e.g. [Inverting a function in a certain region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/inverting-a-function-in-a-certain-region/2328#2328).