# how to plot the inverse of a function

Tags: plotting

I have 3 functions all of which are linearized by reciprocal transformations.
1. y=4+2/x      (let x'=1/x)
2. 1/y = 4+2*x  (let y'=1/y)
3. y=x/(4-2*x)or
   (1/y)=4(1/x)-2 (let y'=1/y and x'=1/x)

I am not certain how to plot #2 an inverse function which I call  z=1/y = 4+2*x in Mathematica. It could be thought of as a composition of functions

Can you help? Thank you.

MMarion

Comment: Regarding inverse functions see e,g, [this anser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/inverting-a-function-in-a-certain-region/2328#2328), you can also find `Composition` in the documentation.