# InverseFunction doesn't work well with ConditionalExpression

Tags: functions

I have a polynomial constructed with `InterpolatingPolynomial`. It is not a one-to-one function but I want to have its inverse on some range where it is monotonously increasing.

According to [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/inverting-a-function-in-a-certain-region) I should use `ConditionalExpression`. But it seems that `InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[f, condition_for_my_range]]` still tries to find inverse for a whole function.

Below is my code:

```
f = InterpolatingPolynomial[{{7, 0}, {1, 0}, {4, 0}, {2.5, 0}, 8, 10}, #] &;
Plot[{f[x],3}, {x, 1,5}, AxesOrigin->{1,0}]
finv = InverseFunction[(ConditionalExpression[f[#],4.1<#<4.9]) &];
finv[3]
```

[image: How it looks like in Wolfram|One]

I get warning `InverseFunction: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverse` and output `2.56775`. I've expected something near `4.4`.

It seems that Mathematica finds the second root of f(x)=3, not the fourth, despite the fact I've set the range for roots explicitly. The same problem in both in Mathematica Desktop 12.1 and Wolfram|One.

It it a bug, or a mistake in my understanding how these things should work?

Comment: As a workaround, use `FindRoot`: `finv := Module[{x}, x /. FindRoot[f[x] == #, {x, 4.5}] &]`

Comment: @Bob thanks, looks like a good workaround :) But it's strange that `InverseFunction` can't solve quite a simple problem