# How to symbolically solve this transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, trigonometry

The equation below shows up when dealing with geodesic curves on elliptic paraboloids:

\begin{equation} u-c^2=u(1+4c^2)\sin^2\left(v-2c \ln\left(k(2\sqrt{u-c^2}+\sqrt{4u+1})\right)\right)  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Obtaining a solution for $v(u)$ is rather straightforward using Solve, like so:

```
Solve[u-c^2==u(1+4 c^2) Sin[v-2c Log[k (2 Sqrt[u-c^2]+Sqrt[4u+1])]]^2,v,Reals]
```

[output omitted]

It would be much more convenient to find the inverse function $u(v)$, so I tried solving for $u$, but MMA gave up with "... cannot be solve with the methods available to Solve".
That's when I gave Reduce a shot:

```
Reduce[u-c^2==u(1+4c^2)Sin[v-2c Log[k\left(2 Sqrt[u-c^2]+Sqrt[4u+1]\right)]]^2,u,Reals]
```

Same message as before.

Is there a way to make this equation more tractable for Mathematica, to let it arrive at a symbolic solution for $u(v)$?

NB: $c$ and $k$ are constants, more precisely $c,k \in \mathbb{R}$; $u \geq 0$ ($u$ denotes the radius)

---

**Edit:**
How can we obtain the paraboloid geodesic $(1)$ above?

First, define the paraboloid surface as follows:

\begin{equation}(u,v)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{u}\cos{v} \\ \sqrt{u}\sin{v} \\ u \end{pmatrix} \tag{2}\end{equation}

In order to trace out a complete paraboloid, let $u\geq 0$ and $v \in [0,2\pi)$. I would rather use $r$ and $\varphi$ to make their meaning a little more clear, but let's stick to the usual naming scheme w.r.t. differential geometry.

Next, calculate the general solution to the geodesics using the Euler-Lagrange equation:

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}+2v\,'\frac{\partial Q}{\partial v}+v\,'^2\frac{\partial R}{\partial v}}{2\sqrt{P+2Qv\,'+Rv\,'^2}}}_{\displaystyle{=0}}-\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{Q+Rv'}{\sqrt{P+2Qv\,'+Rv\,'^2}}\right)=0
\end{equation}

$P, Q, R$ are the coefficients of the first fundamental form; I managed to verify that the solution indeed matches equation $(1)$ given in the literature, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803293/paraboloid-geodesic-evaluate-integral).

Rearrange $(1)$ so we have $v(u)$, and use that inside $(2)$ to describe geodesics that travel across the paraboloid surface.

I was able to come up with a Notebook which computes the integration constants $c,k$ to yield the specific geodesic passing through two points $(u_1,v_1),(u_2,v_2)$.

However, if these points have the same "height" on the paraboloid, that is $u_1=u_2$, Mathematica won't find a solution. I assume knowing the inverse function $u(v)$ would be helpful here.

Comment: At best you can find an inverse series `InverseSeries[
 Series[c^2 + (1 + 4 c^2) u Sin[v - 2 c Log[k (2 Sqrt[-c^2 + u] + Sqrt[1 + 4 u])]]^2, {u, 0, 4}]]` but it's extremely unlikely you'll ever find a closed form inverse for a transcendental problem like this. Only numerical solutions are possible, and that might include fixed point iteration too.

Comment: This could be a good question if you'd provide appropriate meaning of constants and variables with more or less detailed information how the equation can be derived from description of geodesics.  I guess that the parametrisation in terms of  `u` and `v` is not optimal, nevertheless providing appropriate restriction on the variables and parameteres one would get much more. If one can use $v(u)$ it is also possible to have $u(v)$ using `InverseFunction` with appropriate restrictions although I cannot promise that analytical formula can be obtained.

Comment: In any case it would be constructive to play with e.g. `Manipulate[ContourPlot[u-c^2==u(1+4 c^2) Sin[v-2c Log[k (2 Sqrt[u-c^2]+Sqrt[4u+1])]]^2,{v,-4,4},{u,0,8},AspectRatio->Automatic,ContourStyle->Thick],{c,-3,3},{k,0.1,3}]` to get an idea what one could expect.

Comment: @Artes: added some info to my post above.

Comment: I have never seen `ContourPlot` used in this way - how would I find an exact solution, if there is any?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I use `InverseFunction`. Although it does not generate an analytical expression, you still end up with something which returns an exact result rather than an approximate one:

```
lhsMinusRhs[c_, k_][u_, v_] := u-c^2 - u(1+4 c^2) Sin[v-2c Log[k (2 Sqrt[u-c^2]+Sqrt[4u+1])]]^2
assumptions[c_, k_][u_, v_] := u >= 0;
uFunction[c_, k_][v_] :=
  InverseFunction[
    Function[{u},
      ConditionalExpression[
        lhsMinusRhs[c, k][u, v],
        assumptions[c, k][u, v]
      ] // Evaluate
    ]
  ][0] // Evaluate;
```

For example, `uFunction[3, 4][5]` will return an exact `Root` object corresponding to $(c, k) = (3, 4)$ and $v = 5$.

```
uFunction[3, 4][5]
(* Root[{..., 16.33...}] *)
lhsMinusRhs[3, 4][%, 5] // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

Note that `InverseFunction` makes no guarantees on which branch of the inverse will be chosen. If I am after a specific branch, the approach I take is to make `assumptions` specific enough to pin down the unique value corresponding to that branch.

Comment: It seems that `InverseFunction` might have a bug: [(219309)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219309)

Comment: Your code for `uFunction[3, 4][5] // N` returns approximately 16.33 on my machine as well, so I tried to plot `uFunction` to see how it behaves for different values of $c,k$: `Manipulate[Plot[uFunction[a, b][val] // N, {val, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {{a, 3}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 4}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`, but I get an empty plot, no matter what...

Comment: (1/2) @user2286339 I'm not sure why this happens, but `InverseFunction` seems reluctant to evaluate when supplied with inexact input; compare the output of `uFunction[3, 4][5] // N` and `uFunction[3, 4][5.] // N`. An empty plot results because `Plot` numericises the sampling values of `val`.

Comment: (2/2) If the goal is to make a plot, I would not go down the analytical route. Instead I'd make a numerical function, e.g. `uNumerical[u0_][c_, k_][v_] := FindRoot[lhsMinusRhs[c, k][#, v] &, {u0}]` (where `u0` is the initial guess), which is much faster to plot: `Manipulate[Plot[uNumerical[15][a, b][val] // N, {val, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {{a, 3}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 4}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: Originally, I wanted to rearrange eq. (1) in terms of $u$ which seems to have no analytical form, when @Artes hinted at using `ContourPlot` to find it, if there is one. How would I do that? His code snippet above (ContourPlot) suggests a `2\Pi` periodicity, but that is all that I was able to gather from the plot.